# Does a inner join perform as fast as a where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets assume I have two tables

```
create table a 
(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    b_id int,
    Index bid (b_id)
);

create table b
(
    id int primary key auto_increment
    name varchar(100)
);

insert into a values (1, 1), (2, null), (3, 2), (4, null), (5, 3);
insert into b values (1, 'a'),(2, 'b'),(3, 'c');
```

And I need all rows from table a which have a value in row 2. so I can simple do an inner join

```
select * 
from a
inner join b on a.b_id = b.Id
```

In real I have about 5 tables i need to join in a query. So my question is:

Would it be faster to add a where clause to avoid searching for rows where b_id is null or is this not needed?

```
select *
from a
inner join b on a.b_id = b.id
where a.b_id is not null
```

Comment: What if there were null values in table B?

Comment: Null value as a primary key?

Comment: In addition to Nathan's answwr, never use `SELECT *`. Always name (and qualify) columns you want returned. And use indexes for performance.

Comment: this is only a quick example. Of course I do not use select * in any real code

Comment: Your lattermost where clause is redundant. There is no way that the join specified can realize a resultset with a null b_id - whether or not where'ing it out has any impact on performance is something only you can measure in your context. Take a look at the query plan with and without to assess if it makes any difference

Answer (score 2):

The where clause excluding nulls is not  needed.

Don’t worry about nulls getting returned by the join matching null ids; null isn’t equal to itself, so the inner join won’t match any nulls in one table to nulls in another.

Use joins for relating tables. Use where for filtering. There is some overlap in what you can do with these but it’s a style issue. Performance gains come from making sure your code isn’t doing more work than it needs to (such as by making sure it makes use of the indexes).

Also be aware that columns that are part of a primary key can’t be null.